# convert byte array to actual string in serial communication

Tags: java, serial-port

I am using [jSerialComm](https://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/) library for lab machine interfacing.
when we read data from COM Port we got row output.
How can we convert byte array row data to actual result. following my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SerialPort comPort = SerialPort.getCommPort("COM1");
        comPort.openPort();     
        comPort.setComPortParameters(9600, 8, 1, SerialPort.NO_PARITY); 
        reading_bytes(comPort);
    }

    public static void reading_bytes(SerialPort comPort){       
        comPort.addDataListener(new SerialPortDataListener() {
            @Override
            public int getListeningEvents() {
                return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE;
            }

            @Override
            public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
                if (event.getEventType() != SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE)
                    return;
                byte[] readBuffer = new byte[comPort.bytesAvailable()];
                int numRead = comPort.readBytes(readBuffer, readBuffer.length);                 
                System.out.println("Read " + numRead + " bytes.");
                for (byte b : readBuffer)
                    System.out.print(b + ",");
                System.out.println();
            }
        });     
    }
```

we got output:

```
Read 14 bytes.
9,25,35,6,-18,89,-19,-64,65,62,108,56,116,126,
Read 0 bytes.

Read 14 bytes.
58,70,6,32,-117,28,7,6,7,-97,3,7,50,15,
Read 0 bytes.

Read 14 bytes.
96,56,-93,71,-121,51,0,-4,56,-94,96,-39,32,51,
Read 0 bytes.

Read 14 bytes.
-112,-93,-62,-40,58,116,6,14,14,14,14,6,6,13,
Read 0 bytes.
```

now according to machine manual we have to got output format like this:

```
O|1|LID668||^WBC^^\^RBC^^|R||20030516161149||||A||The
patient is abc.|||Dr. xyz||sus.blasts^?\var.
lymph^++||100^\^|1.00^2.0^3.0^4.0^5.0^6.0^7.0^8.0^^^^
^^8.0^10.0^11.0^12.0^13.0^14.0^15.0^^^^^||||Q<CR>
```

How can we convert byte array to required string?
thanks in advance:

Comment: your input data is 56 bytes, I believe you have more in the formatted output??? I would try with a larger buffer (512 or so, just 14 is way to small (I do not trust `bytesAvailable`))

Comment: `@CarlosHeuberger` we not given completed output. it is more than 100 rows. could you give me best solution for encoding my output.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the desired byte array as a parameter to the String constructor.

```
String result = new String(readBuffer);
```

Code sample for your desired output.

```
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
            if (event.getEventType() != SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE)
                return;
            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[comPort.bytesAvailable()];
            int numRead = comPort.readBytes(readBuffer, readBuffer.length); 
            String result = new String(readBuffer);
            System.out.println(result);
        }
```

Comment: we already tried this, when we pass desired array to string parameter we got garbage value like this. G7D¨EÊ…¨ä´§ŒFÇ§cÓoNÔ¦B

Comment: @JitendraRajauriya Have you tried adding Charset as arguement to the String consturctor, like this: String result = new String(readBuffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

Comment: @JitendraRajauriya And if UTF 8 does not work then use the encoding that produced the byte array.

Comment: we also tried using UTF_8 and got 9#~????>l?t?

Comment: @JitendraRajauriya Do you know what encoding is used on the original text?

Comment: when we using encoding to hex like Integer.toHexString(byte), then got 22,ce,aa,2039,e7,c8,45,e5,a2,201a,25,a8,e4,aa,e4,e

Comment: `@TasosKokkinidis` could you give me some example for encoding

Comment: @JitendraRajauriya I believe you have to check how data is formatted, that is, not only encoding but also details like starting/ending sequences, lengths, ...

Comment: `@CarlosHeuberger` thanks you understood my problem but before encoding we can not format like starting/ending. and we tried different way but still not able to encoded my output.